# programatically create a UI Pan Gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

I am using a 3rd party library where it works when the user pans the view  (uses `UIPanGestureRecognizer`)

However, i want to call this method on button click. Therefore, how do i hardcode `panning` in my code, so i need not have to edit the `3rd party library`.

In other words how do i programatically create a `UIPanGesture` ?

I hope that my question is clear, and can someone help me here.

code from 3rd party library:

```
- (void)vPannedHorizontally:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gesture

{

   ...

 }
```

Button Click event from my `ViewCOntroller`:

```
-(IBAction)clickedNow:(id)sender{



 ThirdPartyLib *tpl =[[ThirdPartyLib alloc]init];

[tpl vPannedHorizontally: ??????]; // I need to hardcode a UIPanGesture so it works.

}
```

UPDATE

```
#import "ContentViewController.h"
#import "PaperFoldView.h"

@interface ContentViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) PaperFoldView *paperFoldView;

@end
@implementation ContentViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        UIBarButtonItem *flipButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                       initWithTitle:@"Flip"
                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                       target:self
                                       action:@selector(flipView:)];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = flipButton;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)flipView:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Hi");
    [self.paperFoldView setPaperFoldState:PaperFoldStateLeftUnfolded animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Well the 3rd party library must have a callback for panning events. You could try calling the `performSelector:@selector(theirCallback:) withObject:yourGestureReco` where `yourGestureReco` is an instance of `UIPangGestureRecognizer` where you set all the parameters (state, translation, ...). Is this not an option?

Comment: can you show me a detailed example ?

Answer (score 0):

Every gesture recognizer gets a callback method to which they respond when something happens to them (change of state, ...). So your 3rd party library must have a callback. By callback I mean the `[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panCallback:)]` in which case `- (void)panCallback:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender` would get called on whoever instantiated the recognizer.

What you want to do is find out the name of the callback in your 3rd party library. Then create a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on which you set all the required things like translation.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *reco = UIPanGestureRecnogizer.new;
[reco setTranslation:CGPointMake(20, 20) inView:self.view]; //Or whatever you want
//reco.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged; //If you want this too you'll have to subclass it

//Now call the callback and pass your gesture recognizer
[my3rdLibraryClassInstance performSelector:@selector(panCallback:) withObject:reco];
```

Hopefully this clears things up a bit.

**EDIT:** As for the Fold library I noticed that there are some methods that you can probably use for folding by hand.

1. Set the direction by setting the property `paperFoldInitialPanDirection`
2. Call `animateWithContentOffset:(CGPoint)point panned:(BOOL)panned` on the  fold view and set the point appropriately

Play a bit with the parameters. I'm not sure that it will work but I think it should (I just glimpsed the implementation quickly). Report what happens when you try it.

**EDIT 2: FINAL SOLUTION**

If you want to open the view the library already provides methods to do this. Just call the

```
[self.paperFoldView setPaperFoldState:PaperFoldStateLeftUnfolded animated:YES];
```

This was tested with the demo project included. And you're done.

Comment: It still doesn't work for some reason. The library i use is `https://github.com/honcheng/PaperFold-for-iOS` . I need to have the page fold for a button click instead of `panning`

Comment: I am still stuck. I tried and set `paperFoldInitialPanDirection ` to `PaperFoldInitialPanDirectionHorizontal` and also `animateWithContentOffset:CGPointMake(5.0,5.0) panned:YES` , but it still doesn't work. Help.

Comment: I downloaded the library and posted the solution.

Comment: I too downloaded the project and added a button, and upon button click i fired the line of code you provided me. However, nothing happend. Please look at my post, i have added the code.

Comment: Hey, i am still stuck here. Can someone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to simulate the gesture for this.

Call the methods on the PaperFoldView to manually fold/unfold.

```
-(IBAction)open:(id)sender
{
   //For some reason the timerStepDuration is set to 0 by default so you need to set this otherwise there won't be an animation.
   self.paperFoldView.timerStepDuration = 0.02;
   [self.paperFoldView setPaperFoldState:PaperFoldStateLeftUnfolded];
}
-(IBAction)close:(id)sender
{
   //For some reason the timerStepDuration is set to 0 by default so you need to set this otherwise there won't be an animation.
   self.paperFoldView.timerStepDuration = 0.02;
   [self.paperFoldView setPaperFoldState:PaperFoldStateDefault];
}
```

Comment: After setting `setPaperFoldState` what else should i do. Because currently the view doesn't flip or appear.

Comment: I tried your solution, but the side bar doesn't appear. help